# Oracle SQL: ORA-01858 error on date fields

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have many tables with a date in their name. For example `MY_TABLE_2021_06_01, MY_TABLE_2021_06_02, etc`. I'm trying to extract the date from the table name and see if any tables are more than an year old. This is my code:

```
select * from (
  select
      table_name,
to_date(substr(table_name,-2,2)||'/'||substr(table_name,-5,2)||'/'||substr(table_name,-10,4),'DD/MM/YYYY') TABLE_DATE
  from
      all_tables
  where
      owner = 'my_schema'
      and table_name like '%_20%'
)
where
    TABLE_DATE < trunc(sysdate)-365;
```

The above code works fine if I don't include the where clause `where table_date < trunc(sysdate)-365`. If I run the code with the where clause then I get the

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
> 01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
> *Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
> incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
> required by the format model.
> *Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
> elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.

I tried a different and long-winded approach to see if I can get my code to work and it still throws the same error. My new code:

```
select * from (    
  select table_name, case when table_date < old_date then 1 else 0 end as OLD_TABLE from (
    select
        table_name,
    to_date(substr(table_name,-2,2)||'/'||substr(table_name,-5,2)||'/'||substr(table_name,-10,4),'DD/MM/YYYY') TABLE_DATE,
        trunc(sysdate)-365 OLD_DATE
    from
        all_tables
    where
        owner = 'my_schema'
        and table_name like '%_20%'
    )
 )
where 
    old_table = 1
order by
    old_table desc;
```

Again the above code works fine if I don't include `where old_table = 1` clause but gives the same ORA-01858 error when the where clause is included. I don't understand this because the field `OLD_TABLE` isn't a date field but still getting a date format error.

Comment: `"I have many tables with a date in their name"` - Why? This sounds like a bad idea. Data (and this includes the date) belong inside the dataset of the table, not in its name. If this is about quick access and deletion of complete days, you may consider partitioned tables, but don't create a table per date.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, not in my hands unfortunately. That's how the source system generates these tables and I just have to ingest them as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all tables that satisfy these conditions:

```
      owner = 'my_schema'
  and table_name like '%_20%'
```

have "valid" date format, or it doesn't match format mask you used.

**Note**: if table name is `MY_TABLE_2021_06_01`, why do you `TO_DATE(..., 'DD/MM/YYYY')`?

`2021_06_01` certainly isn't in `DD/MM/YYYY` format, but rather `YYYY_MM_DD` or `YYYY_DD_MM` (can't tell, `06` can be both month or day; the same goes for `01`). *Maybe* your code will start working once you fix that.

If not, then list all tables with names like `%_20%` and see which one(s) of them violate rules you set.

---

Example which works for me: sample tables first:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE my_table_2021_06_01
  2  (
  3     id   NUMBER
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE some_other_table_2020_02_17
  2  (
  3     id   NUMBER
  4  );

Table created.
```

Query to extract tables whose "names" are older than 1 year:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     tables
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT table_name,
  5                TO_DATE (REGEXP_SUBSTR (table_name, '\d+_\d+_\d+'),
  6                         'yyyy_mm_dd') datum
  7           FROM all_tables
  8          WHERE     owner = 'SCOTT'
  9                AND table_name LIKE '%20%')
 10  SELECT table_name
 11    FROM tables
 12   WHERE datum <= ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE), -12);

TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
SOME_OTHER_TABLE_2020_02_17

SQL>
```

Comment: That's what I first checked but all the tables do satisfy those conditions. Luckily my table list is small, so I did go through each field manually and found they are all ok. As a sanity check, I created a column called TABLE_DATE + 1 and it incremented all the dates by a day. And if you look at my substr concatenation, I'm extracting DD first then MM and YYYY, that's why my TO_DATE is in DD/MM/YYYY. I did try with YYYY-MM-DD at first and got the same error.

Comment: I added an example which shows how you might do that; works OK for me.

Comment: I replaced my to_date() with your version of to_date() and it worked all fine :)

Comment: Great, I'm glad if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this logic to extract the dates:

```
select to_date(substr(table_name, -10) default null on conversion error, 'YYYY_MM_DD')
```

This should then work for comparisons to `sysdate`.

This both handles table names that don't match the format and simplifies the date arithmetic.

Comment: getting a `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` error with that one

Comment: @Anish: I suppose you are using an old Oracle version that doesn't yet support the `DEFAULT ... ON CONVERSION ERROR` clause